How do i fix my numbers not showing when using the LineNumberFactory function in javafx?
I tried using the LineNumberFactory function to add line numbers but they only show as grayish rectangles How it looks
I tried to add the .lineno and .fold-indicator classes in my css file (like this)
.fold-indicator{
-fx-background-color:#292929;
}
.fold-indicator .lineno{
-fx-fill:#4a4a4a;
}

and change the background and text color but it didnt do anything. This is how my java code looks:
    private Node createTextAreaBox() {
 mainCodeArea = new CodeArea();
        mainCodeArea.setId("mainCodeArea");
        mainCodeArea.setParagraphGraphicFactory(LineNumberFactory.get(mainCodeArea));
 if(initialText){
            mainCodeArea.replaceText(textAreaText);
        }
        else{
            mainCodeArea.replaceText("");
        }
}

any ideas as to what could be wrong?

First provide css class name(styleClass="code-area") on the code area
<CustomCodeArea fx:id="codeJsonResponse"
                styleClass="code-area"
                minHeight="-Infinity"
                minWidth="-Infinity"
                AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0"
                AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0"
                AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0"
                AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0"
                VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS"/>

after that define the css like below
.code-area .lineno {
    -fx-background-color: blue;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

I was testing the logic here. It worked in my local. 
Reference:https://github.com/FXMisc/RichTextFX/issues/1124
